# How to insert media into the sdcard of the emulator....?

Tags: android, android-emulator, media

Failed to push the item(s).

(null)

This is the error I am getting while i am tried to push the media into the sd card in DDMS
of my eclipse. sdk version is 2.3.1

Its inserting images fine but not .mp3 or .mp4 why..?

Thanks in advance....!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe file is too big? Alternatively you can try the adb tool that comes with SDK:

```
adb push local /sdcard/target
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html

Comment: how to refer to the sdcard path of emmulator in a terminal

Answer (score 3):

If you do not select the emulator on the list on the left, in the devices tab, it would give this error, once selected, try pushing or dragging dropping file from the explorer and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the directory you are trying to push into is not write protected and that the size of the file does not exceed available storage space.